# Magento 1.9 How to add js to order review tab?

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript

I want to hide an the tax row, but I dont know when is generated so I can add some js to hide it.
    [image]

Answer (score 0):

Tax code you can get here

> app/design/frontend/package/themename/template/tax/checkout/tax.phtml

so hide it according to page condition like as check if you are in checkout page etc

```
// Check for checkout page page
if (Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction()->getFullActionName() == 'checkout_index_index') {
    // The current page is the checkout
}
```